# Derivative of a sum w.r.t its limits

Tags: calculus, definition, discrete-calculus

As an analogue of $$\frac{d}{\,dx} \int_a^x f(y) \,dy = f(x)$$

Could we define something for an expression of the derivatives of partial sums; something like $$\frac{d}{\,dn} \sum_{k=a}^n f(k)$$?

Comment: $n\in{\mathbb N}$? It is a discrete variable....
What about to take $\lfloor x\rfloor$ as upper bound of the sum, with $x>a$ for example?

Comment: Check out the sections of Donald Knuth's _Concrete Mathematics_ on discrete calculus. I briefly discuss it in my paper here, chapter 2: http://www.math.tamu.edu/~szroberson/ConcreteMath_SZR.pdf

Answer (score 3):

It is well known that:

$$\frac{d}{dx} g(x) = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}.$$

This makes sense when $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{A} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.
If $g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{A} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then the limit used for defining the derivative loses its meaning.

For the discrete case, we can introduce the **difference** operator, in place of the derivative:

$$D g(k) = g(k+1)-g(k).$$

Specifically, this operator is also known as **forward difference** operator. Check this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#difference_operator) for further details.

It is interesting to notice that:
$$\sum_{k=a}^n D f(k) = \sum_{k=a}^n [f(k+1)-f(k)] = \\
= [f(a+1)-f(a)]+[f(a+2)-f(a+1)]+\ldots = f(n+1) - f(a),$$

which is somehow similar to:

$$ \int_a^x \frac{d}{\,dx}f(y) \,dy = f(x)-f(a)$$

Moreover, if we call

$$F(n) = \sum_{k=a}^n f(k),$$ 
then:

$$D \sum_{k=a}^n  f(k) = F(n+1) - F(n) = \sum_{k=a}^{n+1} f(k) - \sum_{k=a}^n f(k) = f(n+1).$$